# Remove double quotes only if it between character Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string inside variable **a** contains double quotation inside double quotations :

Input :

```
a = ""comment_text": "Siti Sa"diah I need this for my neighbor needs""
```

Expected result :

```
a = ""comment_text": "Siti Sadiah I need this for my neighbor needs""
```

I tried using

```
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', a)
and I also tried this one:
re.sub('"', '', a)
```

but it resulting like this :

```
commenttextSitiSadiahIneedthisformyneighborneeds
and this
comment_text: Siti Sadiah I need this for my neighbor needs
```

I want to delete double quotation(") **only** if it between alphabets.

I'm using python for this one. Is anyone could find a way to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your supposed input isn't valid Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub(r'(\w)"(\w)', r'\1\2', df['comment'])` for any word character around `"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex  :

```
r'\b\"\b'
```

The `\b` is called a word boundary. It matches the position between a word character and a non-word character (in this case `"`), or the beginning or end of the string.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pNh7H1/1)